# Spelling "God" god

Tags: grammar

Is it safe to assume that if a person regularly spells "God" with a lower case letter g for a whole book that he is trying to portray to you that he is not religious?

Why do some writers do this when it is clear that the g should be upper case?

Comment: There are any number of reasons a writer might choose to do that. There's a whole movement of people who lowercase their own names and the pronoun "I," presumably to de-emphasize the ego in pop culture. Maybe it's similar to that. Or maybe this writer was writing about *a* god, without using the word as a proper noun. Without context, this is unanswerable. So I would say no, it's not safe, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: Please give an actual example. What is this book? There are plenty of gods in mythology that can be described as "a god", "that god" or just "gods".  I do tend to agree that 'God' as a name should have an upper-case letter, regardless of which god you are describing.

Comment: What do you mean "it is clear that the g should be upper case"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Gramarist](http://grammarist.com/style/god-capitalization/) offers a 'grammatical' view on this issue:

> - God is capitalized when it functions as a name. In this use, God is a proper noun like any other name and does not take a definite or indefinite article. ***But in phrases like the Biblical god and a forgiving god, which do have articles, there’s no need to capitalize god because it is a common noun rather than a name—yet many religiously inclined writers still capitalize the word in these instances***
> - When the noun god is used generically, especially in reference to a non-Biblical god, it is not capitalized.
> - ***English speakers also traditionally capitalize the pronoun He in reference to God.*** This remains a common practice among people of faith, ***but it is by no means obligatory.***
> - In phrases like for God’s sake, by God, and thank God, the word is capitalized because it generally refers to the god of the Bible and treats the word as a name.

Comment: Both Deuteronomy and Exodus contain the phrase "You shall have no other gods before Me."; which distinctly *does not* preclude the existence of other gods. That implies the possibility of a set of gods, all of which may be called god; and if they're being addressed directly, God.